# Eclipse solutions without a gateway

Tags: mqtt, eclipse-iot

I'm currently reading the Eclipse IoT documents for a big scale company.
Knowing that having a Raspberry as a Gateway means more costs, do you guys think that Eclipse solutions for a MQTT connection will work without a gateway?

Comment: As a nice practice, if you refer to something, please add references (URLs). That will improve your chances of a answer.

Comment: If your node devices already speak IP protocols, have a reasonable amount of volatile and non-volatile storage, and have an outgoing network connection they should be able to connect directly with an MQTT broker.  But if they use some other radio standard like zigbee then you'd need a gateway. Note that a "gateway" often need be little more than a process running on a box - you could likely add this to a customizable WiFi router for example, or an existing on-site server.  You probably would not want to use a Raspberry Pi in a permanent installation or deployment.

Comment: You need to explain a lot more about your scenario for anybody to be able to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If your node devices already speak IP protocols, have a reasonable amount of volatile and non-volatile storage, and have an outgoing network connection they should be able to connect directly with an MQTT broker. But if they use some other radio standard like zigbee then you'd need a gateway. Note that a "gateway" often need be little more than a process running on a box - you could likely add this to a customizable WiFi router for example, or an existing on-site server. You probably would not want to use a Raspberry Pi in a permanent installation or deployment. - @Chris Stratton